# Extracting nested nodes from xml file c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml file:

```
<table head="Film">
<row>
    <id>USD</id><jan>Jan</jan><feb>Feb</feb><mar>Mar</mar><apr>Apr</apr><maj>May</maj><jun>Jun</jun><jul>Jul</jul><aug>Aug</aug><sep>Sep</sep><okt>Oct</okt><nov>Nov</nov><dec>Dec</dec><sum>Year</sum>
</row>
<row>
    <id>2018</id><jan>7629</jan><feb>6433</feb><mar>5573</mar><apr>3676</apr><maj>2545</maj><jun>2542</jun><jul>266</jul><aug>276</aug><sep>2690</sep><okt>371</okt><nov>5446</nov><dec>754</dec><sum>52731</sum>
</row>
```

I'm trying to extract the individual values for every month.
I've tried

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xmlDoc.Load("model.xml"); 
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("table");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList) // for each <testcase> node
{
    Console.WriteLine(node["row"].InnerText);
}
```

This gives an exception because node["row"] is empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your XML is not valid. You need to have a `</table>` on there.

```
//In this example GetXml() just returns your XML
var doc = XDocument.Parse(GetXml());
var rows = doc.Descendants("table").Elements("row").ToList();

foreach(var element in rows[1].Elements()){
    Console.WriteLine(element?.Value);
}
```

Now this is just a basic example based of your XML. You would likely want it to be more robust. You will notice I am showing you this with LINQ, I feel it's more readable than XmlDocument.

Comment: This worked, thanks. The xml document I'm using is valid. I had posted a small part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the child nodes to get your desired result as follow:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("model.xml");
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("table");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList) // for each <testcase> node
{
    foreach (XmlNode row in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode mon in row.ChildNodes)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a valid xml as you are missing </table> in your posted xml.